# Two warring package dependencies have completely blocked APT

Tags: 14.04, apt

I tried and failed to install gnuradio-dev a week ago, and gave up. Little did I know, apparently my botched attemps has put APT into a real bind. Installing, removing, or running dist-upgrade (or any other APT command) leaves me with dependency errors.

I opened Software Center to see if there were suggestions where, and it offered to repair.  That failed, but I did finally get a useful error message:

```
(Reading database ... 333769 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgnuradio-iqbalance_0.37.2-gqrx~trusty6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgnuradio-iqbalance (0.37.2-gqrx~trusty6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgnuradio-iqbalance_0.37.2-gqrx~trusty6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/iqbalance/__init__.py', which is also in package gr-iqbal 0.37.1.5.d4fd4d-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgnuradio-iqbalance_0.37.2-gqrx~trusty6_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gr-osmosdr:
 gr-osmosdr depends on libgnuradio-iqbalance; however:
  Package libgnuradio-iqbalance is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gr-osmosdr (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnuradio-osmosdr0.1.4:amd64:
```

Attempting to install libgnuradio-iqbalance leaves me with this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgnuradio-iqbalance
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 77 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/91.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 555 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 333769 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgnuradio-iqbalance_0.37.2-gqrx~trusty6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgnuradio-iqbalance (0.37.2-gqrx~trusty6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgnuradio-iqbalance_0.37.2-gqrx~trusty6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/iqbalance/__init__.py', which is also in package gr-iqbal 0.37.1.5.d4fd4d-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgnuradio-iqbalance_0.37.2-gqrx~trusty6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't need gnuradio on here - I am happy removing it, but I get the dependency errors when I apt-get remove.  I worked through the first part of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) (up to the PPA part) but no dice.

Other ideas? Even nuclear? Perfectly willing to just nuke all the gnuradio stuff and get a working machine back.

Comment: Did you try removing `gr-osmosdr` too? `sudo apt-get remove libgnuradio-iqbalance gr-osmosdr`.

Comment: Holy crap. I ... I didn't know you could do that.  Worked perfectly.  Put in a regular answer so I can gift you with imaginary Internet points.

Comment: I was able to resolve this same problem (but on 16.04) by following the instructions at: http://gqrx.dk/download/install-ubuntu specifically, I think the apt-get purge commands are what fixes the problem. Then reinstalling gnuradio and gqrx seems to go smoothly. I haven't had an issue with the packaging system and upgrades since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `gr-osmosdr` too. `sudo apt-get remove libgnuradio-iqbalance gr-osmosdr`

Comment: He did. Read the existing posts. He did what I asked.